# How to convert binary int array to hex char array?

Tags: c, arrays, binary, hex

Say I have a 32 bit long array of 32 binary digits and I want to output that in Hex form. How would I do that? this is what I have right now but it is too long and I don't know how to compare the 4 binary digits to the corresponding hex number

This is what I have right now where I break up the 32 bit number into 4 bit binary and try to find the matching number in binaryDigits

```
char hexChars[16] ={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'};
char * binaryDigits[16] = {"0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101","0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1011","1100","1101","1110","1111"};

int binaryNum[32]= {'0','0','1','0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','0','1','0'};
int currentBlock, hexDigit;
int a=0, b=1, i=0;
while (a<32)
{
    for(a=i+3;a>=i;a--)
    {
        current=binaryNum[a];
        temp=current*b;
        currentBlock=currentBlock+temp;
        b*=10;
    }
    i=a;

    while(match==0)
    {
        if(currentBlock != binaryDigits[y])
            y++;
        else
        {
            match=1;
            hexDigit=binaryDigits[y];
            y=0;
            printf("%d",hexDigit);
        }
    }
}

printf("\n%d",currentBlock);
```

Comment: A "32 bit binary array" is not possible in C. But you can use some "packed" version of that, which can is called `uint32_t` in general in C. On a typical PC-OS `unsigned int` would also be possible. All current digital computers only know binary data.

Comment: Your `binaryNum[32]` array holds the ASCII character values of  `'0'` and `'1'`, not `0's` and `1's`...

Comment: I can get the 4 "bit" blocks, for example, the first one I'd get is 0010, but It displays as "10" and I dont know how to compare that with the binaryDigits

Comment: Again, this is where there is ambiguity. Your 4 "bit" blocks (`char *binaryDigits[16]`) is actually an array of `16` *character pointers* to `5-character string literals` (including the *nul-terminating* character). Each *character* is a `byte` (`8-bits`). You can get a binary number from the strings by comparing `binaryDigits[0-15][0-4]` against `'0'` and `'1'` and then left-shifting `<<` the number of positions required. But like I say, there are a lot of gymnastics involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize if this isn't the crux of your issue, but you say

> I have a 32 `bit` long array of 32 binary digits

However, `int binaryNum[32]` is a `32-integer` long array (`4 bytes` per `int`, `8 bits` per `byte` = `4 * 8 * 32` which is (`1024` bits)). That is what is making things unclear.

Further, you are assigning the *ASCII character values* `'0'` (which is `0x30` hex or `48` decimal) and `'1'` (`0x31`, `49`) to each location in `binaryNum`. You can do it, and do the gymnastics to compare each value to actually form a

> 32 `bit` long array of 32 binary digits

but if that is what you have, why not just write it that way? (as a *binary constant*). That will give you your `32-bit` binary value. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    unsigned binaryNum = 0b00100001000010010000000000001010;

    printf ("\n binaryNum : 0x%8x  (%u decimal)\n\n", binaryNum, binaryNum);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/binum32

 binaryNum : 0x2109000a  (554237962 decimal)
```

If this is not where your difficulty lies, please explain further, or again, just what you are trying to accomplish.